# Convert 2 element list into dict in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I am having 2 element list which is like this,

```
a = ['first_name', 'user']
b = ['last_name', 'abcd']
```

I want to convert it into,

```
{
  'first_name' : 'user',
  'last_name' : 'abcd'
}
```

This is what I tried:

```js
a = ['first_name', 'user']
b = ['last_name', 'abcd']
new_dict = {}
new_dict[a[0]] = a[1]
new_dict[b[0]] = b[1]
console.log(new_dict)
```

Are there any simple/native JS method than this?

Comment: I hope that's not passwords being stored in plain text.

Comment: it is just an example.. i want to do similar thing

Comment: `[a,b].reduce((p,c) => p[c[0]] = c[1], {})`

Comment: nice but you missed return.. var o = [a,b].reduce(function(p, c) { p[c[0]] = c[1]; return p; }, {}); it works

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed Yup just realized it. Even added a comment under @[Skymt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/387863/skymt)'s answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place the a and b arrays in an outer array, and then reduce that array into a single object.

```
var o = [a,b].reduce(function(p, c) { p[c[0]] = c[1]; return p; }, {});
```

Comment: Ah! forgot `return p` in my comment. :-p

Comment: Also, you'd need a proper function body (not just the lambda expression you wrote) for that..

Comment: You can try something like this as well `[a,b].reduce((p,c)=>(p[c[0]] = c[1], p), {});`, though I'd prefer using your code.

Comment: Didn't think of that! Clever! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.assign` with `map()` and spread syntax.

```js
var a = ['first_name', 'user'], b = ['last_name', 'abcd']

var obj = Object.assign({}, ...[a, b].map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v})))
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) with a previous [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
var a = ['first_name', 'user'],
    b = ['last_name', 'abcd'],
    object = [a, b].reduce((r, [k, v]) => Object.assign(r, { [k]: v }), {});
    
console.log(object);
```